# Can noted weapons be brought into Glarial's Tomb?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I'm considering making a Hardcore Ultimate Ironman - an Ultimate Ironman where I impose the same restrictions as a typical HC. This means I am unable to do the traditional Ultimate methods of using a looting bag and/or suiciding to get an hour of extra inventory space.

As I look at doing the Waterfall and Roving Elves quest, I realize I will need to go without weapons and armor while inside there. I have successfully tested on an alt that I can go to Enterna with noted weapons, but I lack an account with members with sufficient experience to test the tomb.

Does anyone know (or is any kind soul willing to test) bringing noted weapons and armor into the tomb? If so, I can simply note my items to get them into the tomb and do the quest, and I'll only have to risk my runes on the floor. Otherwise, well it might significantly change my strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested for myself, and yes you can go in the tomb with noted armor and weapons.

Here is an image of my character in the tomb with a noted dragon dagger and rune platelegs:

[image: tomb image]

Comment: Awesome! But in the meantime I did some googling and found out I can't note my armor as an ultimate. Thanks for looking into it though!